# Selenium doesnt continue after a button to click is not found?

Tags: class, selenium

```
if (!parent.equals(child_window)) {
                    driver.switchTo().window(child_window);
                    String title = driver.switchTo().window(child_window).getTitle();
                    j++;
                    System.out.println(j + " " + title);

                    try {
                        driver.switchTo().window(child_window).findElement(By.cssSelector("button.reply_button.js-only")).click();
                        Thread.sleep(9000);
                    } catch (NoSuchElementException ignored) {
                        System.out.println("No Element found");
                        continue;
                    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ignoredxx) {
                        System.out.println("No Element found");
                        continue;
                    }
```

Am clicking a button to open a pop up. Its working but when the button is not found on the page i get this error

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

. I have tried to put continue statement in a catch block but its not working at all.

Comment: Just a curious question please, why do you have to switch to a child window each time before manipulating it ? when you switch to an iframe or whatever, the driver is pointing directly on it, and then to go back, driver.switchTo().defaultContent...

Comment: And can you please post the whole code ? your loop and your Exceptions imports

Comment: @Mohamed EL AYADI i have a list of links which i loop through clicking  to get single page , that page has a button that pops up when i click a button . Am collecting data from the the page and pop up.

Comment: am still on the learning curve but i think you mean this - if (!parent.equals(child_window)) {
                    driver.switchTo().window(child_window);
                    String title = driver.getTitle();     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.reply_button.js-only")).click();
                    j++;

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code;

```
try {                            

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);    

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(By.cssSelector("button.reply_button.js-only")));

driver.switchTo().window(child_window).findElement(By.cssSelector("button.reply_button.js-only")).click();

}
```